# Codeigniter CSRF - how does it work

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, token

Recently I found out about CSRF attacks and was happy to find out that CSRF protection was added to Codeigniter v 2.0.0.

I enabled the feature and saw that a hidden input with a token is added in forms and I assume that it stores the token in a session too. On POST requests does CI automatically compare tokens or do I have have to manually do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The CSRF token is added to the form as a hidden input only when the `form_open()` function is used.

A cookie with the CSRF token's value is created by the Security class, and regenerated if necessary for each request.

If `$_POST` data exists, the cookie is automatically validated by the Input class. If the posted token does not match the cookie's value, CI will show an error and fail to process the `$_POST` data.

So basically, it's all automatic - all you have to do is enable it in your `$config['csrf_protection']` and use the `form_open()` function for your form.

A good article I found that explains it very well: https://beheist.com/blog/csrf-protection-in-codeigniter-2-0-a-closer-look.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I'm so glad that I chose CI as my framework :)

Comment: Thanks but the link is dead

Comment: Perfect and helpful answer. Saved a lot of time through proper direction. Thank you sir!

Comment: @WesleyMurch I was wondering if you're referring to the cookie that is saved at client-side. Couldn't user manipulate those to cookies to work in their favor ?

Answer (score 3):

Refer this Link -- [Used CSRF Tokens using form helper or Manually](http://www.sks.com.np/secure-your-codeigniter-application-using-csrf-token/)

The article explains how to work around with CSRF Tokens in

- form open with form helper `form_open()` function
- in ajax forms
- ajax/jquery serialization forms

This article also explains about how to "**Disable CSRF for cetain URL's(Which are used as webservice urls)**"

Answer (score 2):

When csrf protection enabled security class checks this token automatically (it compares POST token with COOKIE token)

Answer (score 0):

For **codeigniter4** You can enable CSRF protection by altering your `app/Config/Filters.php` and enabling the csrf filter globally:

```
public $globals = [
        'before' => [
                //'honeypot'
                'csrf'
        ]
];
```

Change the name here `app/Config/App.php`

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross Site Request Forgery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
    | checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
    | recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
    |
    | CSRFTokenName   = The token name
    | CSRFHeaderName  = The header name
    | CSRFCookieName  = The cookie name
    | CSRFExpire      = The number in seconds the token should expire.
    | CSRFRegenerate  = Regenerate token on every submission
    | CSRFRedirect    = Redirect to previous page with error on failure
    */
    //public $CSRFTokenName  = 'csrf_test_name';
    public $CSRFTokenName  = 'form_csrf';
    public $CSRFHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
    public $CSRFCookieName = 'csrf_cookie_name';
    public $CSRFExpire     = 7200;
    public $CSRFRegenerate = true;
    public $CSRFRedirect   = true;
```

If you use the form helper, then `form_open()` will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in your forms. If not, then you can use the always available `csrf_token()` and `csrf_hash()` functions

```
helper('form');//::::Load form helper

echo form_open('/u/sign-up', ['csrf_id' => 'my-id']);
```

**will return:**

```
<form action="http://example.com/index.php/u/sign-up" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" id="my-id" name="form_csrf" value="964ede6e0ae8a680f7b8eab69136717d" />
```