# PHP Codeigniter - Prevent Direct URL Access Form Submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone knows how to prevent direct URL Access for Submitting Form?

So I have routes like this

```
$route['registration']=administration/register
```

When I typed

```
localhost/myweb/registration
```

There's a database error, indeed that's because we directly access it by URL without submiting form. I have succeed set validation on my form to prevent database error, but that's in case user submit our form. When it comes user typing "registration", database error.

Well, for some work and pages, I just simple set SESSION as ADMIN or USER, to prevent direct URL access, but we can't do that to form, right?

Notes: My Form Submit data was fine, I just don't know how to prevent user typing "registration" as words of submit execution

Comment: give your controller's 'register' action code so that you can get help by example.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your route in `appliaction/config/routes.php`. Like this

```
$route['registration']='administration/register';
```

This redirects `localhost/myweb/registration` to `localhost/myweb/administration/register`.

Comment: That's not what I meant. So when user doing a form submit data, clicking the submit button, the URL will change from "administration" (page name) to 'registration'. I don't have problems with routes. So 'registration' word is simply have same function as submit button, but by URL.

I can set concept of redirect user when form is empty, but how to put that concept in controler

Answer (score 0):

To stop direct form submission in Codeigniter you can use CSRF protection.

All you have to do is enable it in your $config['csrf_protection'] in application/config/config.php

$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;

and use the form_open() function for your form.

This will stop user from submitting form directly.

Here is are few links for clarification,
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html
[Codeigniter CSRF - how does it work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244669/codeigniter-csrf-how-does-it-work)