# Undefined variable on Codeigniter when try to pass data from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new at Codeigniter. I try to pass some data into a view. I have a route like this:

```
$route['accounts/(:any)'] = 'accounts/$1';
```

and in my Account class i have register function like this:

```
public function register()
    {
        $csrf  = array(
            'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        );
        $this->load->view('partials/head');
        $this->load->view('partials/nav');
        $this->load->view('auth/register',$csrf);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    }
```

then in my register.php i try to print that $crsf like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

when i access my page which in compro.xyz/accounts/register it give me this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: csrf

Filename: auth/register.php

Line Number: 13

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\application\views\auth\register.php
Line: 13
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\application\controllers\Accounts.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

" value="
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: csrf

Filename: auth/register.php

Line Number: 13

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\application\views\auth\register.php
Line: 13
Function: _error_handler

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\application\controllers\Accounts.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\compro\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

" />
```

seem's like my register doesn't recognize `$csrf`. I really have no idea what can cause it, I usually using Twig and since it Codeiginter I don't know much about it. And currently I'm using latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$csrf` will not be an variable on the view.

`name` and `hash` will.

If you want to have `$csrf` you need this data array:

```
$csrf  = array(
    'csrf'=> array(
        'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
        'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
    )
);
```

**But**, if you use the helper `form_open` you don't need to write your own input hidden.

Also, you can use `$this->security` inside the view.

Comment: i don't use form_open since i use Ajax to validate and sent data. that why i need to check it manually.

Comment: i see. ok i will use it seem like more efficient. by the way, if i want to validate get_csrf_token_name() and get_csrf_hash() and compare both of it with the input i just write above right?

Comment: Do you have CSFR enabled in config?

Comment: If yes, it will automatically validated.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

> ```
> $data = array(
>         'title' => 'My Title',
>         'heading' => 'My Heading',
>         'message' => 'My Message'
> );
>
> $this->load->view('blogview', $data);
> ```

Therefore, you can see that **`$data` is not available in the view**, but `$title`, `$heading`, and `$message` are.

Likewise, **`$csrf` won't be available in your view**, but `$name` and `$hash` will. For clarity, rename `$csrf` to `$data`.

```
$data  = array(
    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);
$this->load->view('auth/register', $data);
```

**Edit - A cleaner way to write and understand it is:**

```
$this->load->view('auth/register', array(
   'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
   'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
));
```

Comment: still got same problem now it said Undefined variable: data

Comment: The variable passed to `$this->load->view` is never available to the view. It's _contents_ are extrapolated into new variables for use. Try using `$name` and `$hash` instead.

Comment: one more thing, do you know how to check this csrf is valid?

Comment: It should be handled for you automatically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244669/codeigniter-csrf-how-does-it-work.

Comment: that when i'm using form_open and your solution above still won't work.

Comment: when i'm not using form_open i have to check it manually. but i think i found already on the documentation.

Comment: Your AJAX form needs to pass it to your application but the actual validation happens automatically - as long as you're sending a _post_ request.